# Can I use filter to extract values from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an array of objects:

```js
const books = [
  {
    title: 'Book',
    author: 'Name'
  },
  {
    title: 'Book2',
    author: 'Name2'
  }
];
```

I'd like to extract the titles into an array using the **filter** method. So far I tried this but the array returns with the 2 original objects:

```
const getTheTitles = function(array) {
   const filteredArray = array.filter(function(book) {
      return book.title;
   })
   return filteredArray;
}
```

I also tried this but it results in an empty array (not sure why):

```
const getTheTitles = function(array) {
   const filteredArray = array.filter(function(book) {
      book.title;
   })
   return filteredArray;
}
```

I understand that this could be accomplished using map. But I am trying to accomplish it using filter.

Comment: What you need is `map`, not `filter`: `const titles = books.map(book => book.title);`. `filter` is for **FILTER**ing not for mapping

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

You can read about filter method here, it clearly does not do what you are trying to achive

Comment: Thank you. As mentioned, I am aware of being able to use map. Is there a way to do it using filter? Or is it impossible as I won't be able to specify a criteria for filtering?

Comment: with filter you can only decide which item of the array should be in the filterd array, but you can not change the item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use `Array#filter` to remove items but not to transform them. The filter function is applied to each item. If the function returns `true` (or anything that is *truthy*) the item is kept otherwise it is removed.

Example: keeping only odd numbers:

```js
[1,2,3,4,5].filter(n => n % 2 !== 0);
//=> [1,3,5]
```

Example: removing `false` from an array of booleans:

```js
[true,false,true,false].filter(b => b);
//=> [true,true]
```

What you're trying to do is to transform all items. e.g. from `[{n:1},{n:2},{n:3}]` to `[1,2,3]`. In this case you need `Array#map` which applies a function to all items and creates a new array with the results:

```js
[{n:1},{n:2},{n:3}].map(o => o.n);
//=> [1,2,3]
```

---

**Why does this function return *all* books?**

```js
const getTheTitles = function(array) {
  const filteredArray = array.filter(function(book) {
    return book.title;
  })
  return filteredArray;
}
```

The problem is that your filter function evaluates `book.title` to decide whether to keep the book object. However all your books have a title and therefore this function is the same as saying *"Does this book have a title?"*

**Why does this function return no books at all?**

```js
const getTheTitles = function(array) {
  const filteredArray = array.filter(function(book) {
    book.title;
  })
  return filteredArray;
}
```

The problem is that your filter function doesn't actually return anything *explicitly*. When a function has no `return` statement then it returns `undefined` by default which is a "falsy" value. This function is the same as saying *"Ignore all books"*

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get the titles of certain filtered books, then either do it by chaining `map` to `filter`, like so:

```
let filteredBookTitles = books
  .filter(book => book.author === "Some Name")           // first filter (us any criteria here to select only the books you want)
  .map(book => book.title);                              // then get the titles of those filtered books
```

**Demo:**

```js
const books = [{ title: "Animal Farm", author: "George Orwell" }, { title: "Oliver Twist", author: "Charles Dickens" }, { title: "1984", author: "George Orwell" }];

let georgeOrwellBooks = books.filter(book => book.author === "George Orwell")
  .map(book => book.title);

console.log(georgeOrwellBooks);
```

Or by using a `reduce` to do both while looping the array only once, like so:

```
let filteredBookTitles = books.reduce((acc, book) => {   // for each book in the books array
  if(book.author === "Some Name") {                      // if the book matches the criteria
    acc.push(book.title);                                // add its title to the results array
  }

  return acc;
}, []);
```

**Demo:**

```js
const books = [{ title: "Animal Farm", author: "George Orwell" }, { title: "Oliver Twist", author: "Charles Dickens" }, { title: "1984", author: "George Orwell" }];

let georgeOrwellBooks = books.reduce((acc, book) => {
  if(book.author === "George Orwell") {
    acc.push(book.title);
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(georgeOrwellBooks);
```